# Laptop reboots instead of shutting down

Tags: 16.04, shutdown, reboot, lts

**Specs**:

- **OS**: Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS Xenial amd64
- **Laptop**: Acer Aspire E 15 | Model E5-511-C7NE
- **WakeOnLan**: Off

I looked on *stackexchange* and on *Ubuntu* forum, but I couldn't solve it.

**I try to shutdown my laptop, but instead it reboots after 3 or 4 seconds.**

When I first installed the OS, it was fine. The problem started to happen after I `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`, but I already made a clean reinstall of the OS, so the problem is persisting through HD formatting.

I tried editing `/etc/default/grub` to:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash" acpi=force apm=power_off
```

and

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="acpi=noirq quiet splash"
```

And running `sudo update-grub` on both edits.

None of them worked, the computer actually gets stuck in a black screen with lots of lines of code (I waited a lot to make sure it was really crashed), so the line is back to its original:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

I tried shutting down through the GUI (top-left corner options) and the following commands:

- `shutdown -P now`
- `shutdown -H now`
- `poweroff`

Doesn't work.

I also tried some other things I saw around the internet:

- Installing `laptop-mode-tools`
- Turning WiFi adapter off (through the laptop keys, Fn+F3)
- Having something connected to the USB ports (I tried a USB flash
  drive)

None of them worked.

Comment: Just a small note: you want the options to be inside the double quotes, like `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi=force apm=power_off"`.

Comment: I didn't try that. I also thought it didn't make much sense to have the options outside the quotes, but I just used it how I saw it somewhere (either here in stackexchange or in ubuntu forums) :S

Answer (score 1):

I solved by changing from `16.04.1 LTS amd64` to `16.10 amd64`.

**EDIT**: By changing I mean downloading the **16.10 amd 64 OS image** and installing it in the HD after formatting it.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on AskUbuntu.)

Answer (score 0):

After several hours trying to solve that, I was able to find a final solution to my Acer Aspire V5-471.

I have tried everything which user maviz tried in this topic with no results in Mint 18.2 64 bits (GRUB options, wake up in bios, wifi configuration, laptop-mode-tools, kernel update, etc). After a searching in usb issue, I just put that in `/etc/rc.local` before the existing last line `exit 0`:

```
for usb_ports in /sys/bus/usb/devices/usb?/power/control; do 
   echo on > $usb_ports
done
```

It did the trick and I finally could shut down my computer!